# How to handle interactive CLI programmatically in Qt 5 for Windows

Tags: c++, qt, command-line-interface, interactive, qprocess

I have the following interactive CLI -

```
c:\TEST> python test.py    
Running test tool.    
$help    
   |'exec <testname>' or 'exec !<testnum>'    
   |0 BQ1    
   |1 BS1    
   |2 BA1    
   |3 BP1    
$exec !2    
   |||TEST BA1_ACTIVE    
$quit    
c:\TEST>
```

Does anyone know how to do this in Qt5. I try `QProcess`, but it does not handle the interactive command line shown above since the `exec !2` is user defined.

For example, `QProcess` can handle `python test.py` as shown in the following, however, how do we handle the command inside the CLI, such as `exec !2`

```
QProcess *usbProcess;
usbProcess = new QProcess();

QString s = "python test.py"; 
// ??? how do we handle interactive commands, 
// such as 'exec !2' or 'exec !1' and etc ???

usbProcess->start(s);
//usbProcess->waitForReadyRead();
//usbProcess->waitForFinished();
QString text =  usbProcess->readAll();
qDebug() << text;
```

The following is just a sample code and the test.py shall be as it is! I am just trying to find a solution outside the test.py.

```
"""---beginning test.py---"""

from cmd import Cmd

class MyPrompt(Cmd):

def do_help(self, args):
    if len(args) == 0:
        name = "   |'exec <testname>' or 'exec !<testnum>'\n   |0 BQ1\n   |1 BS1\n   |2 BA1\n   |3 BP1'"
    else:
        name = args
    print ("%s" % name)

def do_exec(self, args):
    if (args == "!0"):
        print ("|||TEST BQ1_ACTIVE")
    elif (args == "!1"):
        print ("|||TEST BS1_ACTIVE")
    elif (args == "!2"):
        print ("|||TEST BA1_ACTIVE")
    elif (args == "!3"):
        print ("|||TEST BP3_ACTIVE")
    else:
        print ("invalid input")

def do_quit(self, args):
    print ("Quitting.")
    raise SystemExit

if __name__ == '__main__':
    prompt = MyPrompt()
    prompt.prompt = '$ '
    prompt.cmdloop('Running test tool.')
"""---end of test.py---"""
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First avoid using the waitForXXX methods, use the main virtue of Qt: the signals and the slots.

In the case of `QProcess` you must use `readyReadStandardError` and `readyReadStandardOutput`, on the other hand the program can not be `"python test.py"`, the program is `"python"` and its argument is `"test.py"`.

The following example has been tested in Linux but I think the changes you should make is to set the paths of the python executable and the .py file

```
#include <QCoreApplication>
#include <QProcess>
#include <QDebug>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QCoreApplication a(argc, argv);
    QProcess process;
    process.setProgram("/usr/bin/python");
    process.setArguments({"/home/eyllanesc/test.py"});

    // commands to execute consecutively.
    QList<QByteArray> commands = {"help", "exec !2", "exec !0", "help", "exec !1", "exec !3", "quit"};
    QListIterator<QByteArray> itr (commands);

    QObject::connect(&process, &QProcess::readyReadStandardError, [&process](){
        qDebug()<< process.readAllStandardError();
    });
    QObject::connect(&process, &QProcess::readyReadStandardOutput, [&process, &itr](){
        QString result = process.readAll();
        qDebug().noquote()<< "Result:\n" << result;
        if(itr.hasNext()){
            const QByteArray & command = itr.next();
            process.write(command+"\n");
            qDebug()<< "command: " << command;
        }
        else{
            // wait for the application to close.
            process.waitForFinished(-1);
            QCoreApplication::quit();
        }
    });

    process.start();

    return a.exec();
}
```

Output:

```
Result:
 Running test tool.
$ 
command:  "help"
Result:
    |'exec <testname>' or 'exec !<testnum>'
   |0 BQ1
   |1 BS1
   |2 BA1
   |3 BP1'
$ 
command:  "exec !2"
Result:
 |||TEST BA1_ACTIVE
$ 
command:  "exec !0"
Result:
 |||TEST BQ1_ACTIVE
$ 
command:  "help"
Result:
    |'exec <testname>' or 'exec !<testnum>'
   |0 BQ1
   |1 BS1
   |2 BA1
   |3 BP1'
$ 
command:  "exec !1"
Result:
 |||TEST BS1_ACTIVE
$ 
command:  "exec !3"
Result:
 |||TEST BP3_ACTIVE
$ 
command:  "quit"
Result:
 Quitting.
```

Comment: The code itself works perfect. However I have two additional questions/issues - 1) the program fails by moving the source code to a function of a class, and invoke the function from the main(). It is easy to reproduce and is there a way to fix it? 2) If each of the commands is waiting for something, for example, "exec !1" sends a 'command' to the device and waiting for the response from the device. It looks like the program will "hang" or the screen will be frozen for a UI app, Is there any way to solve this issue from Qt?

Comment: And how can we capture the data in the second issue if the timeout occurs or the process is done?

Comment: @cnm 
the class where you want to embed it is a widget or a QObject?

Comment: @cnm 1) of course, because all the objects are gone by the time the function returns; you'd have to transform it into a class. 2) not at all - the code is driven from the event loop and the UI will be responsible at all times, but please remove the `waitFor`!

Comment: @eyllanesc, I tried a class from both widget and QObject and they all fail.

Comment: @KubaOber, theoretically the connect() and signal suppose can do the job. However, when I place the process.start() in a routine that keeps track of incoming data from USB port, i.e. the data keeps coming in to the port, it actually freeze the screen. The class for the routine is a QObject class.

Comment: I also see this error "QWinEventNotifier: Cannot have more than 62 enabled at one time".  Any thought on this?

Comment: @cnm 
The problem is that if you put everything in a function because there is not something that holds it inside the function it will eliminate everything created from memory, a possible implementation is to make QProcess member of the class, and the lambdas that I used to make them be slots of the class. How are you doing the commands? in my example there is already a pre-established list of commands.

Comment: @cnm You cannot be asking questions about imaginary code. "*I tried a class...*" - sure, you did, and you did something wrong. What do you expect us to do? Divine your mistakes? If you have a new question, with **specific** code in mind - please post it as a new question. Otherwise, if you wish to update your question with some self-contained code that does USB handling - please do so. Otherwise you're wasting everyone's time - yours *and* ours.

Answer (score 2):

1. All processing should be asynchronous; no `waitFor` calls.
2. The data incoming from `QProcess` can be in arbitrary chunks. You need to collect all those chunks, and parse them to determine when a new input prompt is presented.
3. The process should be opened in text mode so that newlines are translated to `\n` independently of the platform.
4. The standard error forwarding can be handled by the `QProcess`.
5. The Python script should not use raw input -- it will hang on Windows. Instead, it should use stdin/stdout, and should return `True` in the `on_exit` handler, instead of throwing an exception.

First, let's factor out the process interrogation to the `Commander`:

```
// https://github.com/KubaO/stackoverflown/tree/master/questions/process-interactive-50159172
#include <QtWidgets>
#include <algorithm>
#include <initializer_list>

class Commander : public QObject {
   Q_OBJECT
   QProcess m_process{this};
   QByteArrayList m_commands;
   QByteArrayList::const_iterator m_cmd = m_commands.cbegin();
   QByteArray m_log;
   QByteArray m_prompt;
   void onStdOut() {
      auto const chunk = m_process.readAllStandardOutput();
      m_log.append(chunk);
      emit hasStdOut(chunk);
      if (m_log.endsWith(m_prompt) && m_cmd != m_commands.end()) {
         m_process.write(*m_cmd);
         m_log.append(*m_cmd);
         emit hasStdIn(*m_cmd);
         if (m_cmd++ == m_commands.end())
            emit commandsDone();
      }
   }
public:
   Commander(QString program, QStringList arguments, QObject * parent = {}) :
      QObject(parent) {
      connect(&m_process, &QProcess::stateChanged, this, &Commander::stateChanged);
      connect(&m_process, &QProcess::readyReadStandardError, this, [this]{
         auto const chunk = m_process.readAllStandardError();
         m_log.append(chunk);
         emit hasStdErr(chunk);
      });
      connect(&m_process, &QProcess::readyReadStandardOutput, this, &Commander::onStdOut);
      connect(&m_process, &QProcess::errorOccurred, this, &Commander::hasError);
      m_process.setProgram(std::move(program));
      m_process.setArguments(std::move(arguments));
   }
   void setPrompt(QByteArray prompt) { m_prompt = std::move(prompt); }
   void setCommands(std::initializer_list<const char*> commands) {
      QByteArrayList l;
      l.reserve(int(commands.size()));
      for (auto c : commands) l << c;
      setCommands(l);
   }
   void setCommands(QByteArrayList commands) {
      Q_ASSERT(isIdle());
      m_commands = std::move(commands);
      m_cmd = m_commands.begin();
      for (auto &cmd : m_commands)
         cmd.append('\n');
   }
   void start() {
      Q_ASSERT(isIdle());
      m_cmd = m_commands.begin();
      m_process.start(QIODevice::ReadWrite | QIODevice::Text);
   }
   QByteArray log() const { return m_log; }
   QProcess::ProcessError error() const { return m_process.error(); }
   QProcess::ProcessState state() const { return m_process.state(); }
   int exitCode() const { return m_process.exitCode(); }
   Q_SIGNAL void stateChanged(QProcess::ProcessState);
   bool isIdle() const { return state() == QProcess::NotRunning; }
   Q_SIGNAL void hasError(QProcess::ProcessError);
   Q_SIGNAL void hasStdIn(const QByteArray &);
   Q_SIGNAL void hasStdOut(const QByteArray &);
   Q_SIGNAL void hasStdErr(const QByteArray &);
   Q_SIGNAL void commandsDone();
   ~Commander() {
      m_process.close(); // kill the process
   }
};
```

Then we could use a logger that acts as a front for a merged log output:

```
template <typename T> void forEachLine(const QByteArray &chunk, T &&fun) {
   auto start = chunk.begin();
   while (start != chunk.end()) {
      auto end = std::find(start, chunk.end(), '\n');
      auto lineEnds = end != chunk.end();
      fun(lineEnds, QByteArray::fromRawData(&*start, end-start));
      start = end;
      if (lineEnds) start++;
   }
}

class Logger : public QObject {
   Q_OBJECT
   QtMessageHandler previous = {};
   QTextCharFormat logFormat;
   bool lineStart = true;
   static QPointer<Logger> &instance() { static QPointer<Logger> ptr; return ptr; }
public:
   explicit Logger(QObject *parent = {}) : QObject(parent) {
      Q_ASSERT(!instance());
      instance() = this;
      previous = qInstallMessageHandler(Logger::logMsg);
   }
   void operator()(const QByteArray &chunk, const QTextCharFormat &modifier = {}) {
      forEachLine(chunk, [this, &modifier](bool ends, const QByteArray &chunk){
         auto text = QString::fromLocal8Bit(chunk);
         addText(text, modifier, lineStart);
         lineStart = ends;
      });
   }
   static void logMsg(QtMsgType, const QMessageLogContext &, const QString &msg) {
      (*instance())(msg.toLocal8Bit().append('\n'), instance()->logFormat);
   }
   Q_SIGNAL void addText(const QString &text, const QTextCharFormat &modifier, bool newBlock);
   void setLogFormat(const QTextCharFormat &format) { logFormat = format; }
   ~Logger() override { if (previous) qInstallMessageHandler(previous); }
};
```

Then we can define some convenience operators to produce modified `QTextCharFormat`:

```
static struct SystemFixedPitchFont_t {} constexpr SystemFixedPitchFont;
QTextCharFormat operator<<(QTextCharFormat format, const QBrush &brush) {
   return format.setForeground(brush), format;
}
QTextCharFormat operator<<(QTextCharFormat format, SystemFixedPitchFont_t) {
   return format.setFont(QFontDatabase::systemFont(QFontDatabase::FixedFont)), format;
}
```

We also need a function that will add text to our log view:

```
void addText(QPlainTextEdit *view, const QString &text, const QTextCharFormat &modifier, bool newBlock) {
   view->mergeCurrentCharFormat(modifier);
   if (newBlock)
      view->appendPlainText(text);
   else
      view->textCursor().insertText(text);
}
```

Finally, the demo harness:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
   QApplication app{argc, argv};

   Commander cmdr{"python", {"test.py"}};
   cmdr.setPrompt("$ ");
   cmdr.setCommands({"help", "exec !2", "exec !0", "help", "exec !1", "exec !3", "quit"});

   QWidget w;
   QVBoxLayout layout{&w};
   QPlainTextEdit logView;
   QPushButton start{"Start"};
   Logger log{logView.document()};
   layout.addWidget(&logView);
   layout.addWidget(&start);
   logView.setMaximumBlockCount(1000);
   logView.setReadOnly(true);
   logView.setCurrentCharFormat(QTextCharFormat() << SystemFixedPitchFont);
   log.setLogFormat(QTextCharFormat() << Qt::darkGreen);

   QObject::connect(&log, &Logger::addText, &logView, [&logView](auto &text, auto &mod, auto block){
      addText(&logView, text, mod, block);
   });
   QObject::connect(&cmdr, &Commander::hasStdOut, &log, [&log](auto &chunk){ log(chunk, QTextCharFormat() << Qt::black); });
   QObject::connect(&cmdr, &Commander::hasStdErr, &log, [&log](auto &chunk){ log(chunk, QTextCharFormat() << Qt::red); });
   QObject::connect(&cmdr, &Commander::hasStdIn, &log, [&log](auto &chunk){ log(chunk, QTextCharFormat() << Qt::blue); });
   QObject::connect(&cmdr, &Commander::stateChanged, &start, [&start](auto state){
      qDebug() << state;
      start.setEnabled(state == QProcess::NotRunning);
   });
   QObject::connect(&start, &QPushButton::clicked, &cmdr, &Commander::start);

   w.show();
   return app.exec();
}

#include "main.moc"
```

The output is, then:

[image: screenshot]

The Python script:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
# test.py

from __future__ import print_function
from cmd import Cmd
import time, sys

class MyPrompt(Cmd):
    def do_help(self, args):
        if len(args) == 0:
            name = "   |'exec <testname>' or 'exec !<testnum>'\n   |0 BQ1\n   |1 BS1\n   |2 BA1\n   |3 BP1"
        else:
            name = args
        print ("%s" % name)

    def do_exec(self, args):
        if (args == "!0"):
            print ("   |||TEST BQ1_ACTIVE")
        elif (args == "!1"):
            print ("   |||TEST BS1_ACTIVE")
        elif (args == "!2"):
            print ("   |||TEST BA1_ACTIVE")
        elif (args == "!3"):
            print ("   |||TEST BP3_ACTIVE")
        else:
            print ("invalid input")
        time.sleep(1)

    def do_quit(self, args):
        print ("Quitting.", file=sys.stderr)
        return True

if __name__ == '__main__':
    prompt = MyPrompt()
    prompt.use_rawinput = False
    prompt.prompt = '$ '
    prompt.cmdloop('Running test tool.')
```

Comment: the code causes memory leak! I am not sure it is inside Qt or Windows. Private Bytes increases to 9,368k from 8,332K and Working Set increases to 25,128K from 23,460K after click 'Start' button five times.

Comment: If you have identified the leak, then you know how to fix it - feel free to submit a pull request to the github repository. Alas, looking at some numbers doesn't identify a leak. The numbers you cite don't mean much. Maybe there is a bug somewhere. Maybe there isn't. The only way to be sure is to use an actual leak detection tool. And that you didn't do. Think of what the code does each time you click "start": it needs to use more memory; log grows! But you don't know if the growth is fully explained by the log growth or not. Ergo, you can't claim a leak - not yet.

Comment: You're absolutely correct what all you mentioned. I used to use purify which is very good tool, unfortunately I don't have it anymore. I did see the private byte as well as working set keep growing when I signal the click N times. I thought you guys might already knew something about it and fixed it, that is the reason I posted that message and see whether anyone encountered the same issue. I still can't find where the leak is coming from. The code by itself looks good to me according to Qt documentation.

Comment: @cnm Run it on linux under valgrind's memcheck and you'll know if it leaks or not. Otherwise it's a waste of time.

Comment: in the example above, is there a programmatic way that QProcess can be run as administrator or root permission.

Comment: @cnm Unfortunately not as of yet. You'd have to edit `qprocess_win.cpp` and use `ShellExecuteEx` with `runas` verb, instead of using `CreateProcess` as Qt currently does.

Comment: trying to run the script that contains opening \\.\PhysicalDrive# which requires admin permission. Got stuck there.

Comment: You can run it indirectly via `cmd`.

Comment: run 'cmd' inside qprocess?

Comment: Yep! `cmd` lets you run a process with administrative privileges.